# Why would I get a Monopod over a Tripod?

Tags: tripod, monopod

I've been using a cheap basic tripod for several difference scenarios recently, specifically panoramas, night time shots, and HDRs. I'm thinking of upgrading to a better tripod (this one is rather heavy and clunky), and it was suggested that a monopod might be better. I don't tend to take much with me other than my camera, so the smaller/lighter, the better. I know that a monopod isn't going to give me quite as much stability as a tripod, but what advantages does it have instead? And can anyone recommend a good quality budget one? Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- portability

  - access to places that don't allow it
  - weight (when hiking)
- mobility

  - in wildlife photography and other similar feats, a monopod is often good enough for long lenses
  - in sports, racing, birding, it can be easier to follow the action
- utility (as a walking stick)
- takes the weight off of big lenses (especially when the shutter speed needed is sufficiently fast for hand-holding)

  - sports (especially when trying to get a low angle for a good perspective and background)
  - airshows
- stick a flash on it and get off camera flash look without much setup
- get higher angles if you have a remote shutter/use self timer
- defense

It can also be very stable if you use it [correctly](http://www.outdooreyes.com/photo5.php3).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've not used a monopod before, so this was definitely worth reading!

Comment: +1, A monopod with a decent quality ball head is versatile enough for almost anything. One with a 'legwarmer' is especially nice for comfort.

Comment: and +1 for walking stick. Had a whiplash in my leg while out in the mountains a few weeks ago, without that stick it's have been time to load me on a donkey to get me down to where we could get to our bus and then to the nearest phone to call for medevac. As is, I could complete the trip though at a slower pace than intended.

Answer (score 8):

Reasons:

- Tripods are banned where you want to take pictures.
- You need some stability but increased mobility from a tripod (concerts or some sports shooting for example).
- You need something lighter to carry and don't intend on taking really long exposures.

I have a [Manfrotto very similar to this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004PKM5XG) and find it perfectly fine.  Depending on your application, you may want to get a head similar to [this tilt head](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001A1POL8).

Comment: I like the Manfrotto tripods, I'll have to see if I can track down a store that actually stocks their monopods. A tilt head would be good, but would also add some extra weight... have to see one in action I think.

Answer (score 0):

Why? It can sometime help you overcome [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12334/why-are-tripods-forbidden-in-some-public-spaces-and-how-to-deal-with-it) kind of troubles.

Comment: Anyone smart enough to explain why the downvote?

Comment: Your answer does not contain any useful information. You have provided a good link, but you should make it clear what the link is, and why the information there is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to risk blurry shots from those once-in-a-lifetime photo opportunities? Of course not! You've already chosen the best travel camera for your trips, but the best tripod may not be suited for your next trip. So you need a specially designed travel tripod that's small enough to pack and tough enough to keep your camera steady for night shots, selfies and amazing interiors.

Comment: OP specifically asks, *but what advantages does it (monopod) have instead?*